# Switch keyboard layout with opt-shift on OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, keyboard-layout

I got used to switch my keyboard layout with Alt+Shift in Windows. On Lion seems it is not possible to assign Opt+Shift for changing kbd layout. Is there any software which will allow me to switch kbd layout with Opt+Shift (or Cmd+Shift)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html)

From its [list of predefined remappings](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html):

```
- Use PC Style "Change Input Method" #1
  Flip between input modes
  (Option_L+Shift_L to Command+Space)
  If you want to use Option_L+Shift_L as modifier, press Shift_L first. (then press Option_L.)
- Use PC Style "Change Input Method" #2
  Flip between input modes
  (Option+Shift_L to Command+Space)
  (Option+Shift_R to Command+Shift+Space)
  If you want to use Option+Shift as modifier, press Shift first. (then press Option.)
```